# Postgresql distinct issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

It needs receiving unique profiles ordered by creation_date. There is following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT profiles.id, COALESCE(occured_at, users_visitors.created_at, visitors.created_at) creation_date FROM "profiles" 
JOIN "visitors" ON "visitors"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" 
LEFT JOIN events ON profiles.id = events.profile_id 
LEFT JOIN event_kinds ON event_kinds.id = events.event_kind_id 
LEFT JOIN users_visitors ON visitors.id = users_visitors.visitor_id 
WHERE (event_kinds.name = 'enter') AND "users_visitors"."user_id" = 2 
ORDER BY creation_date asc
```

`DISTINCT ON (profiles.id)` won't help once it should be used for ordering. `GROUP BY profiles.id, ...` doesn't work as well.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: But which creation_date value do you want if a profiles.id has several different ones? Besides, move the WHERE clause conditions to the corresponding ON clause if you reallt want LEFT JOIN's. As it is now those two execute as regular INNER JOIN's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this `GROUP BY` work? Or which creation_date do you want - if not the max one?

```
SELECT profiles.id,
       MAX(COALESCE(occured_at,
                    users_visitors.created_at,
                    visitors.created_at)) creation_date
FROM "profiles" 
  JOIN "visitors" ON "visitors"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" 
  LEFT JOIN events ON profiles.id = events.profile_id 
  LEFT JOIN event_kinds ON event_kinds.id = events.event_kind_id
                        AND event_kinds.name = 'enter'
  LEFT JOIN users_visitors ON visitors.id = users_visitors.visitor_id
                           AND "users_visitors"."user_id" = 2
GROUP BY profiles.id
ORDER BY creation_date asc
```

Note how I've moved the where clause conditions to get the `LEFT JOIN`'s to perform as `LEFT JOIN`'s.